# Error during Hook script execution

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

If i tend to execute the following script

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS=”$1"
TXN=”$2"

# Make sure that the log message contains some text.
SVNLOOK=/usr/local/bin/svnlook
LOGMSG=`$SVNLOOK log -t “$TXN” “$REPOS” | find  *.cpp |grep “[a-zA-Z0-9]” | wc -c`

if [ "$LOGMSG" -lt 10 ]; then
echo -e “Please provide a meaningful comment when committing changes.” 1>&2
exit 1
fi
```

I am facing the following error:

```
D:\pg\trunk\pg.txt
D:\pg\trunk\pg.txt
Commit failed (details follow):
'pre-commit' hook failed with error output:
find: *.cpp: No such file or directory
svnlook: Can't open file 'svnrepos2/SVN_Scripts_POC./format': No such file or
 directory
.Please provide a meaningful comment when committing changes.
completed!
```

Why do I get the commit message in that case?

Comment: this code should throw the error when cpp files was committed without svn comments...but throwing error for every file commit

Answer (score 0):

Your `LOGMSG` variable capture stdout (standard output), not stderr.

When there is no `.cpp` found, your stdout will be empty, and your condition will always pass.

You need to check first if there are any `.cpp` files (for instance, `[ "$?" = "0"  ]` would test the result of the `find` command), and then, once capture the `find` output, proceed with your `wc` and your test.

Comment: @priya I am not sure how the find could work after a svnlook. A grep could at least detects cpp files in the output. But a find needs a path to operate. I would recommend a script like http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook